# Crop half of an image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, crop, mat, roi

How can I crop an image and only keep the bottom half of it?

I tried:

```
Mat cropped frame = frame(Rect(frame.cols/2, 0, frame.cols, frame.rows/2));
```

but it gives me an error.

I also tried:

```
double min, max;
Point min_loc, max_loc;
minMaxLoc(frame, &min, &max, &min_loc, &max_loc);
int x = min_loc.x + (max_loc.x - min_loc.x) / 2;
Mat croppedframe = = frame(Rect(x, min_loc.y, frame.size().width, frame.size().height / 2));
```

but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Try drawing that rectangle on a paper, what do you expect?

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, I fix the width, but it gave me an error.

Comment: Try drawing also that one... ;D you can't go out of image boundaries

Comment: I edited my post. I think my y should be 0, but idk why other parameter is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Rect` function arguments are `Rect(x, y, width, height)`. In OpenCV, the data are organized with the first pixel being in the upper left corner, so your `rect` should be:

```
Mat croppedFrame = frame(Rect(0, frame.rows/2, frame.cols, frame.rows/2));
```

Comment: Can you pls add the code to get left half and right half of the image.

Comment: @sreenath `Mat halfLeft = frame(Rect(0, 0, frame.cols/2, frame.rows));` 
`Mat halfRight = frame(Rect(frame.cols/2, 0, frame.cols/2, frame.rows));`

Answer (score 11):

Here's a the python version for any beginners out there.

```
def crop_bottom_half(image):
    cropped_img = image[image.shape[0]/2:image.shape[0]]
    return cropped_img
```

Comment: `img[int(img.shape[0]/2):int(img.shape[0])]` in the case that the height and/or width is an odd number.

Answer (score 4):

To quickly copy paste:

```
image = YOURIMAGEHERE #note: image needs to be in the opencv format
height, width, channels = image.shape
croppedImage = image[int(height/2):height, 0:width] #this line crops
```

**Explanation**:

In OpenCV to select a part of an image,you can simply select the start and end pixels from the image. The meaning is:

`image[yMin:yMax, xMin:xMax]`

In human speak: yMin =  top | yMax = bottom | xMin = left | xMax = right |

" : " means from the value on the left of the : to the value on the right

To keep the bottom half we simply do `[int(yMax/2):yMax, xMin:xMax]` which means from half the image to to the bottom. x is 0 to the max width.

Keep in mind that OpenCV starts from the top left of an image and increasing the Y value means downwards.

To get the width and height of an image you can do image.shape which gives 3 values:

`yMax,xMax, amount of channels` of which you probably won't use the channels. To get just the height and width you can also do:

height, width = image.shape[0:2]

This is also known as getting the Region of Interest or ROI

Comment: Under explanation I think the code should read `image[yMin:yMax, xMin:xMax]`